# Convert latitudes and longitudes to utm on the equator (latitudes have mixed signs)

Tags: python, mapping, coordinate-systems, utm

I am using the [utm](https://pypi.org/project/utm/) package and want to convert a set of latitudes and longitudes near the equator. For my use case I do not know the UTM zone before hand.

The following minimal example

```
import utm
import numpy as np
easting, northing, utm_zone, utm_letter = utm.from_latlon(
    np.array([0.1,-0.1]), # latitudes
    np.array([0,0]) # longitudes
)
```

returns

```
ValueError: latitudes must all have the same sign
```

Is there a work around to force all points to be in the same utm zone without an error?

I am aware that in general one should try to keep the coordinates within a sigle utm zone. However this seems very restricting when working on the edge of a UTM zone. Many of the solutions I have found seem to require specifying the UTM zone to convert the coordinates.